# UWP CanvasControl Redraw

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, win2d

I have simple animation which draws a curve animation.
Every OnDraw i use:

```
lines.add(...);
for(int i = 1; i < lines.Count; i++)
    ds.DrawLine(lines[i - 1], lines[i], Colors.Green, 2);`
```

The number of lines is over 10000.
How can I optimize this?

Comment: Just a small hint: Using `i - 1` as index for accessing the `lines` collection will cause an underflow as it is now, because your loop starts with `i = 0`, meaning that the first loop iteration will try to access `lines[-1]`, which usually does not exist.

Comment: my loop starts index = 1, sorry by this example, but how optimize?
Ok another question, how draw on canvas without redraw 60 draw per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only adding lines each time while the previous lines remain unchanged, consider caching your previous drawing results.  Instead of drawing all the lines directly to the CanvasControl, draw them into a CanvasRenderTarget, then draw that rendertarget onto the CanvasControl.  Now you only need to add whatever lines are new to the rendertarget each time, drawing them over the top of all your previously drawn, reused lines.